# Do I need to verify the toll free number we use for messaging that I get thru Twilio?

Tags: twilio

Got an email from Twilio saying that we MAY need to verify the toll free number we for messaging.

We use a number that we get from Twilio. I can't see anywhere to verify so I wonder if maybe we don't need to do this?

*You’re receiving this email from Twilio because you’ve sent messaging traffic on Toll-Free phone numbers within the past 60 days.
What do you need to know?
The messaging industry is changing the message volumes that can be sent over Restricted (previously called “unverified”) and Pending (submitted for verification) Toll-Free numbers. Increased message filtering will also occur in addition to the new limits applied to both Restricted and Pending. If you’ve already verified your Toll-Free numbers, no further action is needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelit here.

You should verify your numbers for the best delivery.

Users who don't verify risk being blocked (Canada), or increasing filtering and daily limits on sending traffic (US).

Here are the [steps on how to Verify](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/5377174717595-Toll-Free-Message-Verification-for-US-Canada#h_01GTCNEAC3ASNVDFY3XF1VH9AC).

Comment: I attempted to register via the Twilio console. I don't think it worked, and when I tried a second time, I get an error. Maybe it takes a while to process and propagate.